# Single sign on with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have `A` and `B` sites. In case a successful login to any of them, I want to be authenticated to other site as well. For transition to each other, I can use a specific URL. There is not any restriction regarding that. I am also using persistent sessions.

How can I provide such a mechanism with Spring Security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a `PreAuthenticationFilter` for this purpose. Basically my filter is checking a parameter at url such `tid`. This `tid` is representing some unique token which is including principal data at database. My preAuthenticationProvider is authenticating user.

`A` site is creating a url which is pointing to the site `B` with a `tid` param. This param is   processed by my new filter. That is the all story.